# Can I sell my premium Minecraft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to try out the premium version of Minecraft on a friend's recommendation, but I might lose interest quickly.

Can I sell my account later on if I lose interest? Or give my user details away?

Comment: **Update:** I bought the game a while back a I'm still playing it :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course - this isn't an MMORPG, there's nothing really tied to your account (other than your avatar), so there's no reason to prevent people selling accounts..

However, for only $13, most people would rather choose their own username, so good luck to you finding a buyer.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't like it and the price goes up in beta, I'll just sell it for what I paid or less.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Notch was unwilling to change one's username if requested.

Comment: Usernames can now be changed, so this answer is mostly irrelevant

Answer (score 9):

Technically, if you read the terms of use for Minecraft, doing this is illegal. Heck, redistributing anyone's copyrighted property for your own purposes is illegal. According to this line in the EULA, it is **illegal**.

> This also means **you cannot sell or rent** the Game, or make it available for access to other people and you cannot pass on or resell any licence keys.

Comment: Read closely. Account Login Details != Game Licence.

Comment: @Pate See my updated answer.

Comment: At the time this questioned was asked the game did not yet have license keys.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I know, I was simply adding new info due to changes in the EULA.

Comment: A game doesn't need a key in order to have a license. If you clicked an "I agree" button, then you signed a license agreement.

Comment: It's not illegal, it's just breaking the Terms of Service. ToS's aren't the law. In the EU, for instance, you can sell the license without an issue: https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20120703/11345519566/eu-court-says-yes-you-can-resell-your-software-even-if-software-company-says-you-cant.shtml .

Answer (score 0):

Worth nothing that no matter what the EULA might say, Microsoft still has to comply with local regulations. [In the EU, you are allowed to resell a licensed piece of software to a third party.](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20120703/11345519566/eu-court-says-yes-you-can-resell-your-software-even-if-software-company-says-you-cant.shtml)

This might become much less convenient this month, as Minecraft transitions from Mojang to Microsoft accounts and these licenses become tied to the primary account used to access all the other Microsoft services (unless you create a dedicated Microsoft account for this specific purpose). But regardless, you won't have any problems in practice. Nobody will come knock at your door or sue you, or even revoke access to a Minecraft account, just because you switched email address, password and shared these credentials with someone else.

If you do, make sure to also attach the original receipt/transaction ID you got over Email when game was purchased, as well as changing the security questions and informing the buyer of the answers. They might need this info to recover access in the future. You probably only want to do this with a friend or someone you know in person – it's pretty easy to get scammed with this kind of exchange, and then who are you gonna go after?

It is also worth mentioning that, even though you can change your username, your past username history will remain visible, for example by going to https://namemc.com and entering your current or prior name.

Comment: Are you really selling the software, though? Anyone can download the game, you’d be selling the account more then the actual software.
Licensing is weird.